# build fail: error CS1061: 'UITraitCollection' does not contain a definition for 'UserInterfaceStyle' and no extension method 'UserInterfaceStyle'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, build, xamarin.ios, msbuild

Build fails when trying to build Xamarin.ios.csproj. Works in debug mode. I just implemented dark/light mode and it works in debug mode, only fails when trying to build. Looked at the SDK version, xamarin version, and macOS hosted agent. Looks fine, but not sure why its not recognizing property 'UserInterfaceStyle'. Anyone ran into this issue before? any idea?

Here's my pageRenderer code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Foundation;
using Mobile.Base;
#if ACCUROUND 
using Mobile.AccuRound;
#endif
#if LOCATE
using Mobile.Locate;
#endif
#if ROGER
using Mobile.Roger;
#endif
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(Mobile.Base.iOS.PageRenderer))]
namespace Mobile.Base.iOS
{

    public class PageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                SetAppTheme();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t\t\tERROR: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        public override void TraitCollectionDidChange(UITraitCollection previousTraitCollection)
        {
            base.TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection);

            if (previousTraitCollection != null && TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle)
            {
                SetAppTheme();
            }


        }

        private void SetAppTheme()
        {
            if (TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark)
            {
                if (App.AppTheme == "dark")
                    return;

                App.Current.Resources = new DarkTheme();

                App.AppTheme = "dark";
            }
            else
            {
                if (App.AppTheme != "dark")
                    return;

                App.Current.Resources = new LightTheme();

                App.AppTheme = "light";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you get the error when building the app under release mode? Or archiving the app? I just build a test project with your code successfully. This error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist.

Comment: not sure if its release mode cuz i am new to xamarin, it works when you try to build in visual studio in debug mode or build without debug, but I am trying to build on azure pipelines in VSTS in  microsoft hosted agent macOS 14, that's where hw it fails to build ios.csproj giving that error - not sure why that's happening,

Comment: It looks like the same problem in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/775115/cs1061-error-when-building-ios-app.html).

Comment: *"Looked at the SDK version, xamarin version, and macOS hosted agent"* - knowing the exact versions could be helpful in helping you with your issue.

Comment: this is the link I posted again, I removed the UITraitCollection property to see if it passes, but I get different error, I have all the versions listed, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790523/build-fail-error-mt2101-cant-resolve-the-reference-system-string-system-st, and this is macosHostedagent14 link installed software: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-10.14-Readme.md